# C# option patterns won't reload

Tags: c#, .net

In this code snippet, "Changed" will show, but "Changed!" won't show.
I suppose the problem is the `.Configure<Profile>(profile => configuration.Bind(profile))`, but how to make this work.

```
    public static void Run()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(path: "Properties/profile.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();

        ChangeToken.OnChange(
            () => configuration.GetReloadToken(),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Changed"));

        new ServiceCollection()
            .AddOptions()
            .Configure<Profile>(profile => configuration.Bind(profile))
            .BuildServiceProvider()
            .GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<Profile>>()
            .OnChange(profile => Console.WriteLine("Changed!"));
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Well, you create a new ServiceCollection instance and the assoiacted service provider, but who's using/working with that new ServiceCollection instance / service provider and/or the concrete IOptionsMonitor<Profile> instance it provides?

Comment: What's generating the change that causes "Changed!" to display? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-7.0) has more. Also, `OnChange` returns an `IDisposable`, so you should be careful to ensure it is disposed of...

Comment: I am learning Option Patterns, the code snippet is for testing. Theoretically it will reload whether there is a consumer consuming the option.

Comment: @Teg not sure if that's true. Why would the `OnChange()` event fire on the `ServiceCollection`?

Comment: @VicF `GetRequiredService`  return the `IOptionsMonitor<Profile>`. It's just a quick way to get the option, The use OnChange in `IOptionsMonitor`

Answer (score 0):

`.Configure<Profile>(profile => configuration.Bind(profile))` I tested it out.
It's the bind of the configuration make the instance won't refill while json it's changing.